# Cancellable NGRX service polling in a Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

How does one poll a service with an effect that stops polling until the returned value of service meets a condition OR the total duration exceeds a timeout threshold?

For example: A backend system is generating a resource, a frontend application can check whether that resource is available by calling a REST api call which returns a boolean. In my NGRX application I would like to poll every 200 ms this api call until this api call returns the boolean true OR the total polling duration exeeds the threshold of 10000 ms.

The following code samples shows a polling mechanism, however, this polling cannot be cancelled nor has a timeout. How is this done?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Effect()
pollEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.START_POLLING)
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 200)
    .switchMap(() => this.myBackendService.getAvailability().map(response => 
       return taskActions.ActionTypes.UpdateValue(response))
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 7):

Had exactly same issue and I could not find answer from internet. It took me some time to make it work. Here is what I did. I noticed where I put 'takeUntil(this.pollingUntil$)' matters, I put it on top since I needed to update store with latest data. If I put it on bottom(commented line), then polling was canceled and I could not update store with latest data.

```
private readonly pollingIntervalMs = 5000;
private readonly maxPollingMs = 600000; // 10 sec

private pollingUntil$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

@Effect()
pollDb$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(infraActions.InfraActionTypes.PollDb),
  switchMap(pollAction => interval(this.pollingIntervalMs).pipe(
    takeUntil(timer(this.maxPollingMs)),
    takeUntil(this.pollingUntil$),
    mapTo(pollAction),
    switchMap(
      (action: infraActions.PollDb) => this.dbService.get().pipe(
        map((dbInfo: DbInfo) => {
          if (meet condition) {
            this.pollingUntil$.next(true);
          }
          return dbInfo;
        })
      )
    ),
//    takeUntil(this.pollingUntil$),
    map((dbInfo: DbInfo) => {
      return new infraActions.PollDbSuccess(dbInfo);
    }),
    catchError(err => of(new infraActions.LoadDbFail(err)))
  )),
);
```

Comment: You just saved me hours of banging my head against a wall - THANK YOU! Btw if anyone wonders how to get a payload in the first switchMap call: it's part of the passed in action: action.payload

Comment: Thank you sir, this also helped me get past an ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like that:

```
@Effect()
pollEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.START_POLLING)
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 200)
    // stop the polling after a 10s timeout
    .takeUntil(Observable.of(true).delay(10000))
    .switchMap(() => this.myBackendService.getAvailability()
      .takeWhile(response => /* do your condition here */)
      .map(response => taskActions.ActionTypes.UpdateValue(response))
    )
  );
```

This way, the polling will stop either:
 - after a 10s timeout
 OR
 - if your condition based on the response is true

**EDIT 1:**

According to your comment, indeed I think you should rather do:

```
@Effect()
pollEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.START_POLLING)
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 200)
    // stop the polling after a 10s timeout
    .takeUntil(Observable.of(true).delay(10000))
    .switchMap(() => this.myBackendService.getAvailability())
    .takeWhile(response => /* do your condition here */)
    .map(response => taskActions.ActionTypes.UpdateValue(response))
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the answer mark as I've found that polling actually does not stop when the condition is true. Here's what happens: when the condition is true, the effect will continue to dispatch the UpdateValue action until the timer of 10000 ms has completed.

Comment: No luck. Chrome network tab now shows one Api call, which result does not meet the condition. Redux dev tools does not show the UpdateValue action. Is there any way I can assist you in debugging faster?

Comment: I just made a plunkr :) I can see the bug here, I think it's because I'm using takeUntil and takeWhile at the same time but I'm not sure. Investigating.

Comment: Thanks a lot @maxime1992 for the answer.

Comment: @maxime1992 the `takeWhile` condition details were the key to getting this to work correctly. The latest version of rxjs requires the boolean condition passed in as the first param--but leaves a second `inclusive` param as optional. Setting this `inclusive` param to true will pass the backend call's result to the `map` method *and* will break the timer.
In the example above, the `takeWhile` line should look like:
`.takeWhile(response => !response.available, true)`.
Obviously rxjs 6+ requires piping but I won't go there...

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter operator to filter data as per your need. filter operator will emit data when condition will true.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Effect()
pollEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(tasksActions.ActionTypes.START_POLLING)
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 200)
    .switchMap(() => this.myBackendService.getAvailability().filter(response => //condition).map(response => 
       return taskActions.ActionTypes.UpdateValue(response))
    )
  );
```

Comment: The filter will not stop the polling and your answer does not solve the timeout issue.

Comment: You can take a static variable in your effect service file and increase value based on time and check in filter that value reached at level you want. If reached cancel the observable.

Comment: This is not the point with RXJS. With functional programming, you should always try to avoid side effects. Working on static variable IS a side effect. Also, it seems way more complicated than what I did, take a look and let me know I'm open to discussion :)